# Apps are rearranged when multiple monitors wake from sleep or power on

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, suspend, amd-graphics, 21.10

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 and have two identical monitors attached to my AMD 5700G system as "joined displays".

When the monitors wake from sleep or are powered back on, it appears that Ubuntu doesn't realize that both monitors are coming back.  Some apps that were located on one monitor are moved to the other monitor.  Which app window moves is not consistent, but at least one app will do this almost every time the monitor comes back.

I suspect what's happening is that the two monitors are not woken simultaneously, so Ubuntu thinks that only one monitor has come back and tries to move all windows to it.  Or something like that.

I have other similar problems.  Sometimes the left and right monitors will swap.  Sometimes the right monitor will not wake up, and I need to power it off and back on again.

Is there any way I can "lock" the monitor orientation and disable Ubuntu's attempts to detect them dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1927948

Comment: Its a shame that this is still an open issue.  I guess not too many people have multiple monitor setups that are impacted?

Comment: I've moved to Ubuntu 22 and don't see this problem any more.  I don't know what changed.

Comment: I have this issue after upgrading to 22.04, even with both monitors being the exact same model. Very annoying.

Comment: And, annoyingly, after a fresh install, not upgrade, the issue is still persistent.